# ios - UIPinchGestureRecognizer scale UIImageView like snapchat app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipinchgesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransformscale

I want to scale imageview at minimum size and even the image view is intractable when it's size is around 5*5 or something near.

[image]

In snapchat Image (sticker) is shrinking at very small size and even it can be intractable to change position and scale.

I have implemented Pan Pinch and Rotate gesture. And also make it resizable but not as like snapchat.

I want help to achieve this. Many thanks.

Comment: If I give you sample code for you can you customize that?

Comment: I would add the gesture recognisers to the view that contains the stickers, and when a gesture begins, check the center of the gesture and find the image that's closest to it, then apply the transform to that sticker.

Comment: Show me your coding

Comment: Now I am here help you.Are you there?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to write a custom class, extending UIView which contains an additional UIImageView. Hook the PinchGestureRecognizer to the UIView and then use their GestureRecognizers Delgeate Methods to resize the UIImageView. this way the tactility doesn't change.

to further optimize it you could initialize the UIView based on the size of the UIImageView and also scale it down to a certain minimum. That way It will feel more natural. Otherwise, if you start "too big" than you have a different issue.

Comment: Yes @samsam i already done that way. and added pinch on uiview and uiimageview too. and uiview is transparent and its min and max scale is defined. when uiimageview smaller than uiview then  uiview's pinch is calling. That's fine and working perfectly. BUT issue is after leaving fingers and again pinching the UIimageview is scaled to uiviews frame and again going to small. So i never able make is small as like snapchat. :(

Answer (score 1):

When you pinch the image,apply the below code

```
NSData *postData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(passYourImageHere, (double)(100-[25 doubleValue])/100);
NSInteger imgSizeBytes = [postData length];
double imgSizeKBytes = ceil((double)imgSizeBytes / 1024);

NSString *strBytes;
if(imgSizeKBytes > 1024) {
    double imgSizeMBytes = (double)imgSizeKBytes / 1024;
    strBytes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f MB", imgSizeMBytes];
}
else {
    strBytes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d KB", (int)imgSizeKBytes];
}

imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:postData scale:0.1];
lblSize.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The shrinked size will be%@", strBytes];
```

Comment: can you please know me what will happen using above byte operation. Is it working if i scale image to bigger. Thanks

Comment: Hi @user3182143 please help me what to do when pinch scale is increase and decrease.

Comment: Today I am on leave as Ramzan.I will help you out.

Comment: Tomorrow I will help you.

Comment: Even when two fingers are not able to touch UIImageView.

Comment: Shall we continue on tomorrow?

Comment: Hi @user3182143 I was not available for somedays due to some medical emergency. Sorry to late reply. As of now i have stop working on above issue. Let you know when again start. Thanks. hope you understand.

Comment: Monday we will look out as now I am out of station.

Comment: Hi @ user3182143 as of now this issue is postponed for some reasons. I'm sure i'll back with you. Give me some time. Thanks

Comment: Ok Sure.I will do for you.